# PHP Display Shell Command Output in a box in Real Time

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code which asks for input then applies `shell.sh $folderPath $bits $group2`

And I would like to have a box where it displays the output of my script exactly how it would've looked if I ran in in a terminal.

How do I do that?

Below is my code.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['folderPath']) && !empty($_GET['folderPath']) && file_exists($_GET['folderPath']) 
    && is_dir($_GET['folderPath']) && isset($_GET['bits']) && isset($_GET['group2'])) {

        $folderPath = $_GET['folderPath'];
        $bits = $_GET['bits'];
        $group2 = $_GET['group2'];

        $run = shell_exec("shell.sh $folderPath $bits $group2");
        echo "shell.sh $folderPath $bits $group2";
        var_dump($run);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="folderPath">Folder Path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="folderPath" name="folderPath">
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="bits">
            <p>Please Choose bits: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="8bits" name="bits"> 8bits <br>
          <input type="radio" value="16bits" name="bits"> 16bits <br>
        </fieldset>
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="audio-type">
            <p>Please Choose Type: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="C12" name="group2"> C12 <br>
          <input type="radio" value="LR" name="group2"> LR <br>
        </fieldset>
        <input class = "submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this question related to Javascript or HTML?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to send your form data somewhere. In your case, it is your same script.

```
<form method="GET" action="path/to/my/script.php">
```

Secondly, [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns output of executed command. You already wrote the code.

```
$path = $_GET['folderPath'];
$bits = $_GET['bits'];
$group2 = $_GET['group2'];
$output = shell_exec("shell.sh $path $bits $group2");
```

Thirdly, display the output where you want.

```
<div><?php print $output; ?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! One thing Im confused about is where do I put ```<div><?php print $output; ?></div>``` In the separate php file or in the actual html file? If it's in the html file how does it get the output of ```$output```?

Comment: Put it there where you want to display the output. You can take <?php print $output; ?> and put it in any HTML element.

Comment: But you're saying I should put the php file separate from my html file right. So if it's separate how is it gonna access the info from my php file?

Comment: I didn't said you to separate them :) Separation will be good practice. If you ask how seperated HTML will get PHP data, the answer is - by GET paremeters/by Javascript (AJAX). In your case you have HTML and PHP in single file, you can use it everywhere you want.

Comment: So from my understanding, this does not show the live output right?

Comment: What means live output? Your command (shell.sh ....) is executed from PHP and displayed in HTML. If your task is to design your HTML like a command line, you need to add CSS and JS to make front-end look like a command line.

Comment: Thank you Tigran :) What I am hoping to accomplish is not only the file output but I want to see how the script is running just like how the output would be spitted out in real time. Not the final output but how the script is running in real time